# Apollo client is giving me an error of 'store already contains an id' - what does that mean?

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

In a react native project I am creating an object and then redirecting the screen to the newly created object's details page and I'm getting this error:

Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Network error: Store error: the application attempted to write an object with no provided id but the store already contains an id of XYZ for this object.

Looking in the database I see that the item is properly created in the previous step.  Navigating to the same screen and item through a list (not after a create and redirect) seems to work fine.  Do I have to wait or somehow set some sort of timing for the apollo store to stay correct?

I'm using the standard apollo client @graphql binding/wrapping

gql:

```
 query getEvent($eventId: ID!) {
    Event(id:$eventId) {
      id
      headline
      photo
      location
      startTime
      creator {
        username
        photo
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

And here's a code snippet

```
@graphql(getEventGql,{
  options: ({route}) => {
    console.log('route params', route.params);
    return {
      variables: {
        eventId: route.params.eventId,
      }
    }
  },
})

@connect((state) => ({ user: state.user }))
export default class EventDetailScreen extends Component {
...
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You have to add `id` also to the `creator` field:

```
query getEvent($eventId: ID!) {
    Event(id:$eventId) {
      id
      headline
      photo
      location
      startTime
      creator {
        id
        username
        photo
      }
    }
  }
```

In general, make sure to add `id` to all subselections of your queries.

Comment: Had this error where there was no need for an id in a nested property but needed the id at the root level, so this answer was helpful. I would appreciate an explanation of why though.

Comment: @ABCD.ca I am not 100% sure, but it seems that some result caching is going on, so you have to provide the unique identifier for apollo client to retrieve it. Makes some sense, but I have not had this issue prior to the release of 1.0.0, so I have temporarily reverted to 0.10.1

Comment: Also be careful include `__typename` or avoid it if you're testing with MockProvider. But in some cases you have to include `__typename` allowing it in the MockProvider